# C# - Select Cell at Bottom Right corner

Tags: c#, excel, interop, excel-interop

I am looking for a way to move my selected cell from the top left to the bottom right. I was trying to use xlDirection but that highlights everything and doesnt allow me to do a combination of movements.

```
A   B   C
1   4   7
2   5   8
3   6   9
```

I start at A and now only want to focus on 9. The size of the excels change so i cant specify the actual cell to look for each time. 
I was hoping there are similar commands as Ctrl+Down or Ctrl+Right that would put me on the cell.

Answer (score 0):

can't you send keystrokes to the object?

Answer (score 0):

A reference for all key strokes can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.sendkeys?view=excel-pia

```
public class Navigator
{
    private Excel.Application excel;

    private Excel.Workbook workbook;

    public void NavigateToBottomRight(string filePath, string worksheetName)
    {
        excel = new Excel.Application();
        excel.Visible = true;
        workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Cast<Excel.Worksheet>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == worksheetName);

        Excel.Range cell = worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
        cell.Activate();

        string controlRight = "^{Right}";
        string controlDown = "^{Down}";

        excel.SendKeys(controlRight, true);
        excel.SendKeys(controlDown, true);

        //Do other work here

        workbook.Save();
        excel.Quit();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!